# Row being inserted above table when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to populate a table using jquery on my website. When I write the HTML manually on the HTML page it works, but when I replace it with a div and use jquery to append html to it, it inserts the HTML just above the table headers.

It is pulling information that the user created on a table on a different tab to ask the user to confirm the input before submitting.

The row I manually enter (Adult, 4.99, 0,) all appear as they should, but the rows appended to div ticketconfirmation appear above the table. The Jquery is called once the user presses continue on the page where they originally entered the data.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Ticket Name</th>
        <th>Ticket Price</th>
        <th>Max Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Adult/td>
        <td>4.99</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <div id="ticketconfirmation"></div>
    </tbody>
```

**JQuery**

```
function getNodes() {
    console.log("Getting node info");
    $("#ticketconfirmation").text('');
    var table = $('#sample_editable_1').DataTable();

    var data = table.rows().data();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#ticketconfirmation").append('<tr>');
        var row = table.row(i).data();
        $("#ticketconfirmation").append(
                "<td>" + row[0] + " </td><td> " + row[1] + " </td><td> "
                        + row[2] + "</td></tr>");
    }
};
```

Comment: i am afraid it because you have invalid html. you cannot put div in that location though

Comment: Yep. The illegally-placed 'div' is being moved outside of (and above) the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove your `<div id="ticketconfirmation"></div>`
and try this one:

```
   var newRow;
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {        
        var row = table.row(i).data();
        newRow = "<tr><td>" + row[0] + " </td><td> " + row[1] + " </td><td> "
                        + row[2] + "</td></tr>";
        $('table.table tbody').append(newRow);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tableRow = $('<tr></tr>');
    var row = table.row(i).data();
    tableRow.append("<td>" + row[0] + " </td><td> " + row[1] + " </td><td> " + row[2] + "</td>");
    $("#ticketconfirmation").append(tableRow);
}
```

You can give the id ticketconfirmation on tbody and remove that div.